# Node / Angular / Passport / Satellizer Token - Based Facebook Authentication not returning token

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook, satellizer

I am using Satellizer on Angular with a Node backend doing authentication with Passport.js. I have implemented the login flow according to the Satellizer documentation and am able to return a token to the browser through my Passport / Node server. **However, when I return the token, it is returned to the popout window, not the Angular application itself.** As a result, I receive this error in the angular application after the popout window self-closes:

```
Expecting a token named "token
```

Here are my passport routes:

```
app.post('/login/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook-login', { 'scope': ['email'] }))

app.get('/login/facebook-callback', passport.authenticate('facebook-login'), function(req, res) { tokenHelper.createSendToken(req.user, res); })
```

And here is my Passport Facebook strategy:

```
var facebookLoginStrategy = new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:8080/login/facebook-callback",
    passReqToCallback: true,
    profileFields: ['email']
}, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    if (!req.user) {
        User.findOne({
            "facebookData.id": profile.id
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if (user) {
                // Authenticate
                console.log('found user')
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                // Register
                console.log('making new user')
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.facebookData = profile
                newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value
                newUser.username = profile.emails[0].value
                console.log(newUser)
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        // Authorize
        console.log('updating user')
        var user = req.user
        user.facebookData = profile;
        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
})
passport.use('facebook-login', facebookLoginStrategy)
```

I installed passport session even though I'm using tokens, but it still returns the token to the wrong place. How can I make Satellizer pass the token it receives in the popout window forward to the angular application? Or do I need to modify my authentication flow to accommodate these frameworks? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Matt, did you ever find a resolution for this. I'm trying to do the exact thing and having issues as described above.

Comment: I decided against using Satelizer and instead created a 'landing' route in my Angular app that I res.redirect() to when the callback from the facebook authentication is called. I.e. if a user authenticated correctly I use res.redirect('/landing/facebook/login/' + token); or if there is an error res.redirect('/landing/facebook/error/' + errorType); This allows me to redirect back to my Angular app after attempting authentication with Facebook.